# What Is The Best Method To Create Edit Forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I'm working on an application in Ruby on Rails (Ruby 2 - Rails 4 - Bootstrap 3)

I have used the simple_form gem to build the forms, like signup and register, but how do you create a form that loads an object from the database and allows a user to edit the details?

Say we had a Product table in the database and I wanted to create a form to load the details of that product into the form and allow the user to edit a product's description, price, etc.

I have had a look around but still not clear.

Thanks.

Comment: Simply use `form_for` or `simple_form_for` helpers. Here's the `form_for` descption and some examples:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

Comment: @MarekLipka I've been using form_for and looking at the guide you sent across, with no luck. Copying the form from them is very simple, but does something have to be declared in the associated Controller? No luck yet! Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to put a link from your view to the edit action where you send the product as a parameter this usually goes in your index (app/views/products/index.html.erb). It should look something like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %>
```

Then you need to make sure you have the edit action in your Products controller (app/controllers/products_controller.rb):

```
 def edit
 end
```

Now your edit.html.erb (app/views/products/edit.html.erb) should look something like this:

```
<h1>Editing product</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Show', @product %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', product_path %>
```

And finally the form you are rendering that should be located in app/views/_form.html.erb should look like this:

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
  <% if @product.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :descriptions %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Tip: When you generate a Scaffold with the rails generate Scaffold command, it automatically creates the edit, delete, show and new actions for your model and all the views and classes I mentioned above.

```
rails generate Scaffold Product name:string description:text price:decimal
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Andres, thanks for the input, but sadly still having issues. The app has been setup by someone else so I'm working with what I have. For some reason all of the error checking on your edit example did not work for me. I also had to change the path of the action button to edit_product_path, the page is working but the fields have not been generated with the data for the relevant object (product). Any ideas?

Comment: I should also mention, do I only need to have the edit action in the property controller or do I need to add more code than what you provided in the great example above?

Comment: You don't need to put more code inside the edit function. Are you passing the product as a parameter to the edit page? If you are using <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %> make sure that "product" is an instance of the object you want to edit.

Comment: Thanks for the input Andres! I have a 'My Products' page that shows all of the brand's products. When they click on the edit button edit_product_path(product.id) it takes the user to the edit page with the form, but the details of that object's instance do not appear in the form fields. So the price field and all the other fields are empty, I want the values for each displayed. Thanks a lot for your help so far Andres!

Comment: Try sending (product) as parameter instead of (product.id) because you want to send the whole object, not just the id.

Comment: Andres, thanks a lot for your help. I finally fixed it, where you earlier said not to put any more code inside the Edit function, I had to place the following: `@product = Product.find(params[:id])`